# mui input Using kebab-case for css properties in objects is not supported. Did you mean MozAppearance?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

at InputBase (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@mui/material/InputBase/InputBase.js:299:83)

Using kebab-case for css properties in objects is not supported. Did you mean MozAppearance?

Using kebab-case for css properties in objects is not supported. Did you mean WebkitAppearance?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the old style for option 'moz-appearance': whatever.  The version of react you are using is now using MozAppearance.  Just switch to MozAppearance: whatever and it will go way.

Answer (score 0):

**Long Story, Short**: If you face this issue, simply remove any CSS vendor prefix (-moz, -ms, -webkit, etc).

**Example - Instead of this...**:

```js
      <Box
        className='logo-2024'
        display='flex'
        flexDirection='row'
        sx={{
          '-webkitUserSelect': 'none',
          '-msUserSelect': 'none',
          userSelect: 'none'
        }}
      >
    </Box>
```

**Prefer this...**:

```js
      <Box
        className='logo-2024'
        display='flex'
        flexDirection='row'
        sx={{ userSelect: 'none' }} //Remove: -webkitUserSelect and -msUserSelect
      >
    </Box>
```

**Short Explanation**: The first code will generate the error: `Using kebab-case for CSS properties in objects is not supported. Did you mean MozAppearance?` and by removing `-webkitUserSelect` and `-msUserSelect` (second example) the problem is solved.

### Why

The error occurs because Material UI automatically adds the vendor prefixes with the use of [jss-vendor-prefixer](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss-vendor-prefixer) and [css-vendor](https://github.com/cssinjs/css-vendor).
Source: ([MUI - Supported Platforms](https://v3.mui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/)).

**What are vendor prefixes?**: CSS experimental properties of each of the most popular browser rendering engines (-webkit-, -o, -ms, --moz, for instance). This, in theory, helped to prevent their experiments from being relied upon and then breaking web developers' code during the standardization process.
**Source**: [Mozilla.org - Vendor Prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)